# Windows x64 2008 P2V? Has anybody had any success?

Tags: windows-server-2008, vss, physical-to-virtual, vmware-converter, x86-64

If I use VMware converter it throws

> Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Unexpected error calling routine CoCreateInstance.  hr = 0x80040154, Class not registered
>   .
>
> Operation:
>      Instantiating VSS server

If I use Disk2vhd it throws

> Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Unexpected error querying for the IVssWriterCallback interface.  hr = 0x80070005, Access is denied.
>   . This is often caused by incorrect security settings in either the writer or requestor process.
>
> Operation:
>      Gathering Writer Data

Has anybody been able to pull this off?  It seems that the VS copy service is throwing a huge wrench into all of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly and answer:
Yep, I've done a few. But I always do it offline. PXE boot WinPE, mount a network VHD, and robocopy it over. A quick bcdedit touchup to detect the new HAL and it's good to boot (more driver installation, integration services, etc from there).

Perhaps there's an equivalent process for VMware images?

Answer (score 0):

I do the disk2vhd all the time no problems, and your sure that your starting the disk2vhd as administrator correct?  Also the volume being backed up has the system account with full control right?